# Can you embed a webpage to a site using a bookmarklet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bookmarklet

I am attempting to create a bookmarklet in which I can go to any webpage, and it will add an embedded webpage to the bottom. I am not good with any jquery/javascript/html, but if you tell me how I'd go about doing it I'd gladly figure it out, but I have no real way of knowing how start this.

Answer (score 0):

The general idea might look like this:

```
javascript:(function() {
    var eltIF = document.createElement("iframe");
    eltIF.setAttribute("src", "http://anysitetogo.com"); 
    document.body.appendChild(eltIF);
    eltIF.scrollIntoView();
})();
```